#  how to remove old data into ArrayList?

Tags: java

in my code have

```
SearchBean sb=new SearchBean();
final static ArrayList<SearchBean> result=new ArrayList<SearchBean>();
public void addData()
{
.
.   (Adding data from data base into SearchBean object
.
result.add(sb);
}
public ArrayList<SearchBean> sendResult()
{
  return result;
}
```

Now i'm `return result`. first time it is giving correct but second time again that object also will be adding.
for example first time searching result `syam`(correct result) 
in second time searching actually `Ram` is the coorrect result but `syam,Ram` also coming...
please help me ...

```
how to remove old data into ArrayList?
```

Comment: I feel @Peter already provided the correct answer, but you should post more code. It is unclear if `sb` and `result` are fields on class (object) level or if they are just local variables inside a method...

Comment: but ArrayList Object i'm using Twice that's way i'm declared global please give me suggestion...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it a local variable instead of a `static` field.

In general, using a local variable instead of a field is a good idea, but in your case it would fix a bug. ;)

---

I would have method like

```
addDataAndSendSearch(); // List is only in this method.
```

or

```
List<SearchBean> list = generateSearch();
sendSearch(list);
```

or

```
List<SearchBean> list = new ArrayList<>();
match1.addData(list);
match2.addData(list);
sendSearch(list);
```

in each case you can see

- I don't re-use a list, global or other wise.
- The list is passed to any method which needs it. There is no chance of getting an old value.

Comment: Thank you... but i'm using that result into another method so global variable created..

Comment: That is a bad idea. If you access it via a global variable, you may or may not see changes when this is not what you want. You should take the result returned and pass it to wherever it is needed instead.

Comment: @NarasimhamK I have added some examples.

Answer (score 1):

Because once you add something in `ArrayList` it remains there unless you call `remove()` or `clear()`